# How can I edit a .rsc file (Extracted from a .sis file)

Tags: symbian, pys60, symbian3, sis

recently extracted a .rsc file from a .sis package, and now I find myself in need of editing it. I distinctly recall Nokia offering software specifically designed for this purpose in the past, but unfortunately, my attempts to locate a working download link have been futile thus far.

If anyone has any insights or suggestions on how to tackle this issue, I would greatly appreciate your input. My aim is to efficiently modify the contents of this .rsc file, and any assistance in achieving that goal would be immensely valuable.